# How can I get a reValue in a specific position of the matrix?

Tags: swift, matrix

I'm new in sprite kit. I'm taking the value at a specific position of a matrix, but I really have a problem when I print that value. The simulator prints: **optional(nil value)** instead of printing just the value.

So, how can I get the reValue in a specific position of the matrix?

Code:

```
NumColumns = 4
NumRows = 4

func matrix() {
    var valor = "0"
    var principal = "0"
    for var column = 0; column < NumColumns; column++ {
        for var j = 0; j < NumRows; j++ {
            valor = "\(numbers[column, j])"
            cont++
            principal = "\(cont)"
            if valor != "0" {
                numbers[column, j] = valor + principal
                println("\(numbers[column, j])") //This print show: optional(nil >value)
            } 
            else {
                numbers[column, j] = principal
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code for creating `numbers`?

Comment: Why aren't you using simd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a two-dimensional matrix of strings with the following:

```
    var numColumns = 4
    var numRows = 4

    // Create a 4x4 matrix of Strings
    var array = [[String]](count: numColumns, repeatedValue:[String](count: numRows, repeatedValue:String()))

    // Assign a string to a matrix element
    array[1][2] = "element at (1,2)"

    println (array[1][2])
```